# Display hoverlabel before value

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe (x,y,z), i want to plot:

- x vs y,
- display z value as hovertext, with label 'z'.

I can get it to display z value but would like to add a label 'z: ' before the value to clarify what it is.
This is the code so far

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
                 'y':[0, 11, 31, 21, 41, 31, 41, 61, 51],
                 'z':[0,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,12] })


fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
   x=df['x'],
   y=df['y'],
   hovertext=df['z'] #displays hover value
   #somehting like: hoverlabel='Z :'
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `hovertemplate` argument:

```
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
   x=df['x'],
   y=df['y'],
   hovertext=df['z'],
   hovertemplate = 'Z: %{hovertext}'
))
```

See more here: https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate

Comment: Great! can this be done with multiple hovertext? hovertex = [df['z],df['x']]?

Comment: OK i found a solution using: 
    hovertemplate =
                   '<i>Y</i>: $%{y:.2f}'   +
                   '<br><b>X</b>: %{x: .1f}<br>'+
                   'Z: %{hovertext}'),

Comment: Yes, you use the other dimensions of the plot.